# Simple mediation analysis - significant indirect effect but no significant total or direct effect

Tags: mediation

I've done a simple mediation analysis, but not completely sure how to interpret the findings. I've found a significant (just) indirect effect, but no significant direct or total effect (see below).

I'm just wondering if anyone has thoughts on how to interpret this? It's not a suppression effect, which is what I've seen in other examples of this happening, as the signs for the ab and c' pathways are both negative. I'm not sure if it is just likely to be a power issue or if there is another explanation that I'm maybe missing.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it's not a suppression effect just because both signs are negative?  If I am reading this correctly, the effect with the mediator is smaller (closer to 0) than without. That's suppression.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that the total effect is "ns," even when either the direct effect or the indirect effect (or both) are significant. The total effect is the sum of direct + indirect effect. The non-significant direct effect may lead to the sum falling below the significance "threshold", even when the indirect effect alone would be significant. And yes, this could be a power issue.

It does not look like suppression to me either since both c and c' have the same sign.

PS: I don't know if that's what you did, but the indirect effect should typically be tested using asymmetric, bias-corrected bootstrap confidence intervals since the product of two path/regression coefficients is not normally distributed. See

MacKinnon, D. P., Lockwood, C. M., & Williams, J. (2004). Confidence limits for the indirect effect: Distribution of the product and resampling methods. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 39(1), 99-128.